# Como crear un Array con un While de la DB?

Tags: php, array, while

Como estan?
Estoy tratando de conseguir ayuda con lo siguiente >

Tengo este Array:

```
   $ComprobanteItem_1 = array(
                  "Cantidad" => 1,
                  "Detalle" => "Producto Uno",
                  "Codigo" => "CODPROD",
                  "IVA" => 21,
                  "PrecioUnitario" =>100,
                  "Total" => 121,
                  "Gravado" => true,
                  "Bonificacion" => 0
                  ),
```

Necesito que un While o algun tipo de Loop, me complete los campos y aumente el identificador ComprobanteItem_X donde X seria el Numero de Array. Todo en base a la Consulta que se realice en la Base de datos. Puede haber 1 como 20 Items en repetir este fragmento de codigo y no consigo que funcione. el Codigo Bruto tendria que quedar asi

```
$items = array(
                $ComprobanteItem_1 = array(
                      "Cantidad" => 1,
                      "Detalle" => "Producto Uno",
                      "Codigo" => "CODPROD",
                      "IVA" => 21,
                      "PrecioUnitario" =>100,
                      "Total" => 121,
                      "Gravado" => true,
                      "Bonificacion" => 0
                      ),
                $ComprobanteItem_2 = array(
                      "Cantidad" => 1,
                      "Detalle" => "Producto Uno",
                      "Codigo" => "CODPROD",
                      "IVA" => 21,
                      "PrecioUnitario" =>100,
                      "Total" => 121,
                      "Gravado" => true,
                      "Bonificacion" => 0
                      ),
                 );
```

Como puedo hacerlo?? gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre solucionarlo, La respuesta fue asi.

```
      $i = 0;

          while ($vhoy = mysqli_fetch_array($ventatabla)) {

          // ARRAY DONDE SE GENERA A PARTIR DE UN $i 0

               $fic[$i] = array(
                "Cantidad" => $vhoy['cantidad'],
                "Detalle" => $vhoy['nombre'],
                "Codigo" => $vhoy['idficha'],
                "PrecioUnitario" =>$vhoy['costodeventa'],
                "Total" => $vhoy['costodeventa'],
                "Gravado" => true,
                "Bonificacion" => 0
                );


           // CUANDO FINALIZA LA SECUENCIA ANTERIOR $i HACE SUMA + 1
           // DE ESTA FORMA EL INDICE DEL ARRAY ($fic[$i]) SE AUTO
           // INCREMENTA HACIENDO QUE EL INDICE FINAL SEA UNICO


              $i++;
          }


print "<pre>";
print_r($fic);
print "</pre>";


$items = array($fic); // ARRAY LIMPIO
```